# Story about a human sized giant

Tags: identification-request

I’m trying to remember the title of a book I’ve read about a short giant in a mountain raised by normal sized giants. The basic plot is that he’s trying to learn to read or something like that. He leaves the mountain for a short while and meets a human girl and then comes back and saves his people (I don’t remember how exactly). I know that he’s picked on by the rest of the giants though. There’s the giants chiefs daughter in it as well, she’s a minor character though. One of the lines is “he’s upside downing me” if it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Muncle Trogg](https://books.google.com/books?id=CDqlSFzRSsIC) by Janet Foxley

> A topsy-turvy fairy tale about a small giant on a big adventure!Let's
>   get ready to grumble! Mount Grumble is where the giants live. But
>   (contrary to what you might think, maybe because of their name) not
>   every "giant" (see?) is, um...big. In fact, Muncle Trogg is so SMALL
>   that all the other giants make fun of him for being (uh-oh)
>   people-sized. And toss him around like a football!Fed up, Muncle Trogg
>   climbs down Mount Grumble to take a look at the Smallings (that would
>   be humans) he supposedly looks like. What he discovers is......a sulky
>   green dragon and a terribly sensible girl? But when Mount Grumble is
>   put in harm's way, it's up to little Muncle to be the bigger smallest
>   giant, prove that size doesn't matter, and somehow save his home!

Answer (score 5):

Could this be **Roald Dahl's [*The BFG*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_BFG)**?

The main characters are a human girl, Sophie, and a giant, the Big Friendly Giant or B.F.G, who lives with a bunch of other giants who are much bigger and fiercer than him and pick on him a lot:

> 'Here comes the runty one!' boomed the Fleshlumpeater. 'Ho-ho there, runty one! Where is you splatchwinkling away to in such a hefty hurry?' He shot out an enormous arm and grabbed the BFG by the hair. The BFG didn't struggle. He simply stopped and stood quite still and said, 'Be so kind as to be letting go of my hair, Fleshlumpeater.'
>
> [...]
>
> Suddenly, the Fleshlumpeater shot out two enormous hands and grabbled the BFG around the waist. He tossed him high in the air and shouted, 'Catch him, Manhugger!'
>
> The Manhugger caught him. The other giants spread out quickly in a large circle, each giant about twenty yards from his neighbour, preparing for the game they were going to play. Now the Manhugger threw the BFG high and far, shouting 'Catch him, Bonecruncher!'
>
> The Bonecruncher ran forward and caught the tumbling BFG and immediately swung him up again. 'Catch him, Childchewer!' he shouted.

The B.F.G goes out into the world to catch the dream of humans, which he can somehow 'read', although his literacy isn't very good:

> You is less or more right,' the BFG said. 'Every dream in the world is making a different sort of buzzy-hum music. And these grand swashboggling ears of mine is able to read that music.'
>
> [...]
>
> Sophie moved over to read what he had written so far. The letters were printed big and bold, but were not very well formed. Here is what it said:
>
> THIS DREAM IS ABOUT HOW I IS SAVING MY TEECHER FROM DROWNING. I IS DIVING INTO THE RIVER FROM A HIGH BRIDGE AND I IS DRAGGING MY TEECHER TO THE BANK AND THEN I IS GIVING HIM THE KISS OF DEATH ...

In the end, he doesn't exactly save the other giants, but he saves the humans of the world from being eaten by them (while not doing them any real harm):

> A fleet of helicopters then follows Sophie and the BFG to the giants' homeland, where the giants are tied up as they sleep, and the helicopters carry them back to London where they imprisoned in a deep pit. After BFG has Fleshlumpeater untied and is hoisted out of the pit, the man-eating giants find themselves being only fed snozzcumbers.
>
> <sub>-- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_BFG)</sub>

Comment: Not quite as the girl is discovered following the HUMAN sized giant child and is captured, then turned into a pet for the giants chiefs daughter. In the bfg there’s no female giants.